# Inner join with array id

Tags: mysql

I have mysql database

```
 A/ id, name
 B/ id, title, A_ids
 A_ids array id table A ex: "1,4,5"
```

Same data

```
A
1; "HaNoi"
2; "HCM";
3; "HP"
B
1; "abc","1,2"
2; "ztz","1"
3; "abc","3,2"
4; "ztz","3"
```

I want result

```
1; "abc","HaNoi,HCM"
2; "ztz","HaNoi"
3; "abc","HP,HCM"
4; "ztz","HP"
```

how can do that?
Thank

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would help up solve your problem if you could include some things you've tried, and why they didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a combination of `find_in_set()` for the join and `group_concat()` for the output:

```
select b.id, b.title, group_concat(a.name order by a.id) a_names
from tableb b
left join tablea a on find_in_set(a.id, b.A_ids) > 0
group by 1, 2
```

See [demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1040c/1) using your sample data.